# PyQt4 scrollbar interacts incorrectly with embedded scenes

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, scrollbar, mayavi

I'm having an issue combining PyQt4 scrollbars (on the MainWindow) with embedded scenes - everything works fine until I resize my window, after which my scenes begin to travel with the scrollbar off the page.

Below is the simplified, full code to illustrate this behavior (with two screenshots attached afterward to explicitly showcase this interaction):

```
import sys, os
from pyface.qt import QtGui, QtCore
os.environ['ETS_TOOLKIT'] = 'qt4'

from traits.api import HasTraits,Instance,on_trait_change
from traitsui.api import View,Item
from mayavi import mlab
from mayavi.core.ui.api import MayaviScene, MlabSceneModel, SceneEditor

class Mayavi_Scene(HasTraits):
    scene = Instance(MlabSceneModel, ())

    @on_trait_change('scene.activated')
    def update_scene(self):
        Mayavi_Scene.fig1 = mlab.figure(1, bgcolor=(.5,.5,.5))
        self.scene.mlab.clf(figure=Mayavi_Scene.fig1)
        testPlot = mlab.test_contour3d()

    view = View(Item('scene', editor = SceneEditor(scene_class=MayaviScene),
                    height=300, width=300, show_label=False),
                resizable=True,
                )

class P1(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(P1, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(20,20,20,20)
        layout.setSpacing(10)

        self.label_edge1 = QtGui.QLabel('')
        self.label_edge1.setMargin(5)
        self.label_edge1.setFrameStyle(QtGui.QFrame.Panel | QtGui.QFrame.Sunken)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_edge1, 0, 0, 10, 10)
        self.label_edge1.show()

        self.label_avgVol = QtGui.QLabel('Test')
        self.label_avgVol.setMargin(5)
        self.label_avgVol.setFrameStyle(QtGui.QFrame.Box | QtGui.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.label_avgVol.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_avgVol, 0, 0, 1, 10)
        self.label_avgVol.show()

        self.viz1 = Mayavi_Scene()
        self.ui1 = self.viz1.edit_traits(parent=self, kind='subpanel').control
        layout.addWidget(self.ui1, 1, 1, 1, 9)

class P2(QtGui.QWidget):    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(P2, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(20,20,20,20)
        layout.setSpacing(10)

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 500)   

        tab1 = P1(self)
        tab2 = P2(self)

        self.tabs = QtGui.QTabWidget(self)
        self.tabs.resize(250,150)

        self.tabs.addTab(tab1, 'Page 1')
        self.tabs.addTab(tab2, 'Page 2')

        self.setWindowTitle('SCROLLBAR ERROR EXAMPLE')

        self.groupscroll = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.groupscrollbox = QtGui.QGroupBox()

        self.MVB = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.MVB.addWidget(self.tabs)

        scroll = QtGui.QScrollArea()
        widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        widget.setLayout(QtGui.QHBoxLayout())
        widget.layout().addWidget(self.groupscrollbox)
        scroll.setWidget(widget)
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.groupscrollbox.setLayout(self.MVB)
        self.groupscroll.addWidget(scroll)
        self.setCentralWidget(scroll)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Before Reframing

[image]

After Reframing

[image]

**Edit:** .gif to show effect (notice how object gets covered up by its own frame containing it at the end instead of moving with it; it's like the 3d scene object isn't being notified that everything else around it is changing):

[image]

Comment: I don't have any issue with this code. Could you explain better when the issue happend?

Comment: @ymmx the issue occurs when I place my mouse on the bottom-most exterior frame of the GUI window and then proceed to drag the window upwards (minimizing it from below).  When the window is minimized past where the scene is, instead of the scene being covered underneath like everything else, it actually begins to move upwards and off the screen (underneath the GUI inner window frame), as seen in picture 2.  The same can happen from left to right when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the place where the scroll bars are added.

```
import sys, os
from pyface.qt import QtGui, QtCore
os.environ['ETS_TOOLKIT'] = 'qt4'

from traits.api import HasTraits,Instance,on_trait_change
from traitsui.api import View,Item
from mayavi import mlab
from mayavi.core.ui.api import MayaviScene, MlabSceneModel, SceneEditor

class Mayavi_Scene(HasTraits):
    scene = Instance(MlabSceneModel, ())

    @on_trait_change('scene.activated')
    def update_scene(self):
        Mayavi_Scene.fig1 = mlab.figure(1, bgcolor=(.5,.5,.5))
        self.scene.mlab.clf(figure=Mayavi_Scene.fig1)
        testPlot = mlab.test_contour3d()

    view = View(Item('scene', editor = SceneEditor(scene_class=MayaviScene),
                    height=300, width=300, show_label=False),
                resizable=True,
                )

class P1(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(P1, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(20,20,20,20)
        layout.setSpacing(10)

        self.label_edge1 = QtGui.QLabel('')
        self.label_edge1.setMargin(5)
        self.label_edge1.setFrameStyle(QtGui.QFrame.Panel | QtGui.QFrame.Sunken)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_edge1, 0, 0, 10, 10)
        self.label_edge1.show()

        self.label_avgVol = QtGui.QLabel('Test')
        self.label_avgVol.setMargin(5)
        self.label_avgVol.setFrameStyle(QtGui.QFrame.Box | QtGui.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.label_avgVol.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_avgVol, 0, 0, 1, 10)
        self.label_avgVol.show()



        self.groupscroll = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.groupscrollbox = QtGui.QGroupBox()



        self.viz1 = Mayavi_Scene()
        self.ui1 = self.viz1.edit_traits(parent=self, kind='subpanel').control

        self.MVB = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.MVB.addWidget(self.ui1)

        scroll = QtGui.QScrollArea()
        widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        widget.setLayout(QtGui.QHBoxLayout())
        widget.layout().addWidget(self.groupscrollbox)
        scroll.setWidget(widget)
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.groupscrollbox.setLayout(self.MVB)
        self.groupscroll.addWidget(scroll)



        layout.addWidget(scroll, 1, 1, 1, 9)



class P2(QtGui.QWidget):    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(P2, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(20,20,20,20)
        layout.setSpacing(10)

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 500)   

        tab1 = P1(self)
        tab2 = P2(self)

        self.tabs = QtGui.QTabWidget(self)
        self.tabs.resize(250,150)

        self.tabs.addTab(tab1, 'Page 1')
        self.tabs.addTab(tab2, 'Page 2')

        self.setWindowTitle('SCROLLBAR ERROR EXAMPLE')


        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In that condition, the scroll bars are inside the tab and not ouside. Then you get something like :

[image]

But I'm not sure if this is what you wanted.

Comment: thank you for testing this out. The inner scrollbar that you've added might be the best alternative. It still feels weird though that the scene moves upwards (literally out of its frame and even disappears) as the window is resized: when you grab the bottom of the window and drag it upwards from its beginning vertical height to vertical height = 0.  Are you seeing the same thing that I am?  All other widgets stay in place.

Comment: Also, try scrolling left and right with the frame set up as in your screenshot. Something weird even happens here, with the scene label moving left and right with the scrollbar drag, but the actual scene object staying in the middle (and getting overshot by the frame eventually if dragged too far).

Comment: I think I don't have this issue. could you provide a GIF with some frames to illustrate what happend?

Comment: thanks for sticking with me on this one!  I've uploaded a .gif as an edit in my initial post

Comment: I don't have this behavior at all... 
I don't see where it could come from in the code neither.

Comment: Maybe you could add a minimum height and width to the window ?

Comment: thanks so much for all of your help. This is really confusing! If I come up with a solution, I'll be sure to post it here.

Comment: I'm wondering if it is an issue due to an old version of pyqt. maybe you could upgrade it. or remove install it again. you could also try to install a pyqt5 instead of pyqt4?

Comment: so looking at my conda environment, I'm currently running `qt=4.8.7=4`, `pyqt=4.11.4` and `mayavi=4.5.0=py27_0`, with pyqt4 appearing up to date after a brew `upgrade`... I've been trying to get the full PyQt5 package running in harmony with Mayavi, Traits, Pyface and VTK, but am running into some rough errors with the GUI activity. I'll make a new topic to get that running, and then will circle back here.