# Add scroll bar into tab PYQT5

Tags: python, tabs, pyqt5, qtabwidget, qscrollarea

I wanted to create a scrollbar(pyqt5) into tab, base on example in link below I did some changes to fit my need but the scrollbar didn't show on tab and my charts become smaller.

example  [PyQt4 - how to add scrollbar into tabbed windows of fixed size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49471331/pyqt4-how-to-add-scrollbar-into-tabbed-windows-of-fixed-size)

import file  https://filebin.net/u3m7m3x2k74wlm6l

```
import sys
import os
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import ( QApplication, QWidget,QHBoxLayout,QVBoxLayout,QPushButton,QTabWidget,QMainWindow,QGridLayout,QSizePolicy\
                            ,QScrollArea,QGroupBox)
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
#import html 
import plotly.offline as po
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

class Win(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()    
        self.setGeometry(100,100, 1280,900)
        self.GuiApp=App()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.GuiApp)
        self.show()

class Tab1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Tab1, self).__init__(parent)

        df = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Python-setup test/Plot122.csv')# need to download the file from https://filebin.net/u3m7m3x2k74wlm6l 
        data1 = px.line(df,x = 'Date', y ='AAPL.Open', color = 'Category')
        fig4 = go.Figure(data1)
        raw_html = '<html><head><meta charset="utf-8" />'
        raw_html += '<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script></head>'
        raw_html += '<body>'
        raw_html += po.plot(fig4, include_plotlyjs=False, output_type='div')
        raw_html += '</body></html>'
#fig_view
        fig_view1 = QWebEngineView()
        fig_view2 = QWebEngineView()
        fig_view3 = QWebEngineView()
        fig_view4 = QWebEngineView()

        fig_view1.setHtml(raw_html)
        fig_view1.setFixedSize(700,600)
        fig_view1.show()

        fig_view2.setHtml(raw_html)
        fig_view2.setFixedSize(700,600)
        fig_view2.show()

        fig_view3.setHtml(raw_html)
        fig_view3.setFixedSize(700,600)
        fig_view3.show()

        fig_view4.setHtml(raw_html)
        fig_view4.setFixedSize(700,600)
        fig_view4.show()

        layoutC = QGridLayout()
        layoutC.addWidget(fig_view1,0,0,1,1)
        layoutC.addWidget(fig_view2,0,1,1,1)
        layoutC.addWidget(fig_view3,1,0,1,1)
        layoutC.addWidget(fig_view4,1,1,1,1)

        self.setLayout(layoutC)     
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Maximum,QSizePolicy.Maximum)


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        #Button
        BT1 = QPushButton('BT1',self) 
        self.layout.addWidget(BT1, 0,0,1,1) 
        

        ##########################################TEST scrollbar in tab ################################################
        tab1 = Tab1(self)

        self.tabs = QTabWidget(self)     
        self.tabs.addTab(tab1, 'Page 1')

        self.groupscrollbox = QGroupBox() 
        self.MVB = QVBoxLayout() 
        self.MVB.addWidget(self.tabs)      
        
        widgetTab = QWidget(self)  
        widgetTab.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        widgetTab.layout().addWidget(self.groupscrollbox) 

        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.scroll.setWidget(widgetTab) 
        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(False)
        self.scroll.setEnabled(True)

        self.groupscrollbox.setLayout(self.MVB) 

        ##########################################TEST scrollbar in tab ################################################  
        self.layout.addWidget(self.groupscrollbox, 0,2,13,1) 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Win()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want to add scrollbar in the red box which the code between "TEST scrollbar in tab" to show all charts with "Date, It will be overlapped when maximize the window.
[image: I want to add scrollbar in the red box which the code between "TEST scrollbar in tab" to show all charts with "Date", it will be overlapped when maximize the window]
Below shows the Charts with "Date" below the charts
[image: This shows the Charts with "Date" below the charts]

Comment: the code is reproducible with the CSV from https://filebin.net/u3m7m3x2k74wlm6l, and both python file and CSV from same directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to put "tab1" is a QScrollArea, and that QScrollArea in the QTabWidget

```
class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        bt1_button = QPushButton("BT1")
        tab1 = Tab1()

        scrollbar = QScrollArea(widgetResizable=True)
        scrollbar.setWidget(tab1)

        tabwidget = QTabWidget()
        tabwidget.addTab(scrollbar, "Tab1")

        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(bt1_button, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(tabwidget, 0, 1, 2, 1)
```

[image]